# How do I run a second code in the same Xcode Project?

Tags: xcode

I have built my first code in a Project that runs at I expected; however, when I tried to add another code to the same project, the compiler still only run the code from before.

The two codes are meant to have no relationships at all, and I have added a separate Target to the second code

[image: This is what it looks like]

The command line output in the picture is the expected output from the first code I wrote.

Comment: I'm use Xcode in my work, but I'm not really sure what you are asking, so it looks to me as if you should clarify a little. Also, please put the picture directly into your post rather than linking to it. Some people don't like following links.

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the right side where it says `Target Membership`, the currently checked box is the code that will be run, in your case the name is DataStruct.

Try to check both options. It should work.